# Registered Models not showing in Django Admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

So I boogered up a migrate and decided it would be easier to go with a db reset.  So I removed the migrations folder, as well as the database.  I then recreated the database, ran `python manage.py migrate`, `createsuperuser`, and went ahead and logged into the admin panel - but to my surprise the models that I have registered no longer show up in the panel.  They were there before this whole thing.  Can anyone give me some insight?  I'm sure I've missed something small and stupid.  The file structure, outside of the migrations folder, has been untouched.

**Models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator

class DetailsModel(models.Model):
   distance = models.SmallIntegerField()
   rate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)

class PhoneModel(models.Model):
    phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$', message="Phone number must be entered in the format: '+999999999'. Up to 15 digits allowed.")
    phone_number = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], max_length=15, blank=True) # validators should be a list

class TravelModel(models.Model):
   mileageRate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=3)

   def __str__(self):
      return '%s' % (self.mileageRate)


class CompanyModel(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   details = models.ForeignKey(DetailsModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

   def __str__(self):
      return '%s' % (self.name)


class SiteModel(models.Model):
   company = models.ForeignKey(CompanyModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   street1 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   street2 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   state = models.CharField(max_length=2)
   zipcode = models.IntegerField()
   country = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class PersonModel(models.Model):
   firstName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   lastName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   company = models.ForeignKey(CompanyModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   phone = models.ForeignKey(PhoneModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE )
   email = models.EmailField()

   def __str__(self):
      return '%s %s' % (self.firstName, self.lastName)
```

**Settings.py (INSTALLED_APPS)**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'main',
    #'rest_framework',
    'debug_toolbar',
]
```

**Admin.py from 'main' App**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from . import models

# Register your models here.

admin.site.register(models.CompanyModel)
admin.site.register(models.SiteModel)
admin.site.register(models.PersonModel)
```

Answer (score 0):

Before running `python manage.py migrate`, you should run `python manage.py makemigrations`.

Comment: That does not help.

Answer (score 0):

I see two possible problems:

1. Try installing your app like this instead:

   ```
   'YOUR_PROJECT.main' #use your project name
   ```
2. Check the permissions of your created user. It won't show if it has not the permissions to change the model.

Comment: '>>> print(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
['django.contrib.admin', 'django.contrib.auth', 'django.contrib.contenttypes', 'django.contrib.sessions', 'django.contrib.messages', 'django.contrib.staticfiles', 'main', 'debug_toolbar']'  I'm logging into django as the superuser I created, if that's the user you're referring to.